# Maven dependency directory not created in target

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku

I'm using Maven 3.3.3 to create a Spring MVC application that can be deployed to Heroku. I intend to use jetty-runner as suggested by the Heroku documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-spring-mvc-hibernate).

I can't get Maven to create the target/dependency folder in which to copy the jetty-runner.jar file. I use the commands:

```
mvn clean
mvn package
```

I get the target directory created, with all resources, web pages and source, but not the "target/dependency" folder where the jetty-runner.jar file should be copied.

My pom.xml is almost identical to the one provided by the sample application in the link above. My project and pom.xml file can be found in the following GitHub repository:

https://github.com/gfigueroa/nlp-tools-spring-heroku

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an activation of your dependency-plugin *outside* the `<pluginManagement>` section:

```
...
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Leave as is -->
      ...
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement> 
  <!-- Add the section below -->  
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>      
...
```

The `<pluginManagement>` section is for declaring *how* your plugins should behave *when* activated. The activation itself is done outside this section.

Comment: Does this mean I only have to add outside of the <pluginManagement> section those plugins that have an <execution> tag ?

Comment: Yes. `<pluginManagement>` works as a place to put your _default_ configurations/executions for plugins. It is not _absolutely_ necessary (but best practice), but if you use a certain plugin in the same way in lots of different places, it's going to save you a lot of repeating. You can always override the defaults outside this section if you need to for specific use-cases. Does this make any sense to you? I am not sure if I am explaining it very well.